# ZF 2 submiting forms using Ajax

Tags: zend-framework2

i searched for a long time for some exemples of ajax forms in ZF2,but there is no explicit tutorials, if someone can help me, i'll be thinkful. **i'm trying to call a controll's action using ajax**

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? No one can tell, there's so many possible ways to answer your question...

Comment: http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/zend-framework-2-using-zend-form-and-ajax/ by https://www.google.de/search?q=zend+framework+2+form+ajax&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1440&bih=764&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=mzOwUaejD8jBtQbK-IG4CQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAA

Answer (score 0):

the zend framework render(output) the HTML as per the layout template, you can assume each action content are snippets than get included in the layout.

So that said to get AJAX response, just disable the layout for AJAX calls, that seems so simple ya, ok

so now where do we add layout disable code, you can do this before any action is invoked to do that include this code in application Module.php, we are attaching an event to check if the call is from AJAX

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e){
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'disableLayout'), 100);  
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}
```

Add a function under the same Module.php

```
public function disableLayout(EventInterface $event){
    $result = $event->getResult();
    if ($result instanceof \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel) {
        $result->setTerminal($event->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest());
        //setTerminal(true) disable the layout
    }
}
```

This is one way of doing it, there are many more ways, if you don't want to disable layout for all request you can simply set the setTerminal(true) fetching the current viewmodel on any action, that need to be called by ajax request, this is just an example that would help to move in the right direction

Comment: first thinks for the interest giving to my question,well after adding this modifications i got this error (Argument 1 passed to Application\Module::onBootstrap() must be an instance of Application\EventInterface, instance of Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), now for th reste i create the ajax call function with URL pointed on my action, and i disable the layout by using this $view->setterminal(true)

Comment: The report says there parameter passed to onBootstrap is not an event boject, just make sure you had copied the lines under onBootstrap I had mentioned to your bootstrap function in Modules.php

Comment: i fixed the probleme on onBootstrap, now i send data width ajax, the posts is empty and as a result the i got an empty inserted row, even the url is right,here is my function ajax:function saveme() {
  $.ajax({
  url:'index',
  type:'POST',
  success:function(response){
  $('#formResult').html(response);
  },
  error: function(response){
  $('#formResult').html(response);
    }

 });
 return false;

 }

Comment: can you post your action code and the action view script contents?, so that, let me know I can help further

Comment: based on your ajax request, it should be yourdomain/index I think for default rout it would point to application/index/index i.e your action is index action in index controller, I need the content of that action and also the respective view script (index.phtml) hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem in that? just use some js library to sent a ajax request and parse the response accordingly. you can call any controller action if you have set the routing correct. just like you access the normal url. You can either send back the JSON response or the HTML response depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**my action code**
    public function indexAction() {
        //$this->layout ( 'layout/pages' );

```
    $this -> id = ( int )$this -> getEvent() -> getRouteMatch() -> getParam('id');
    $this -> id_branche = ( int )$this -> getEvent() -> getRouteMatch() -> getParam('id_branche');
    $this -> form = new CommentForm();
    $this -> form -> get('submit') -> setAttribute('label', 'Add');
    $request = $this -> getRequest();
    //verifie le type de la requete
    if ($request -> isPost()) {
        $user = new user();
        $comment = new comment();
        $blog = new blog();
        print 'j';
        //Initialisation du formulaire e partir des donnees reues
        $this -> form -> setData($request -> getPost());

        //$this->form->setData($request->getQuery());
        //Ajout des filtres de validation base sur l'objet user,comment
        print '2';
        //$form->setInputFilter($user->getInputFilter());
        //Contrele les champs
        if ($this -> form -> isValid()) {
            print '3';
            $user -> exchangeArray($this -> form -> getData());
            $comment -> exchangeArray($this -> form -> getData());
            print '4';
            $validname = $this->checkuser($this->form->getValue('email'));
            if($validname){
            $this -> getUserTable() -> saveUser($user);}
            else{print 'exist';}
            print '5';
            $lastUserId = $this -> getUserTable() -> getAdapter() -> getDriver() -> getLastGeneratedValue('id');
            $this -> getCommentTable() -> addComment($comment, $lastUserId, $this -> id);
            return $this->redirect ()->toRoute ( '#Blog', array ('controller' => 'index',) );
        } else {
            print 'not set';
        }
    } else {

        $viewm = new ViewModel( array('blog' => $this -> getBlogTable() -> getBlog($this -> id, $this -> id_branche), 'comment' => $this -> getCommentTable() -> fetchJoin($this -> id), 'id' => $this -> id, 'id_branche' => $this -> id_branche, 'formComment' => $this -> form, ));
        $viewm -> setTerminal(true);
        return $viewm;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**my view**
$form = $formComment;
)
 $form->setAttribute( 'action', '#');
?>
<h4>Leave comment</h4>
<?=$this->form()->openTag( $form )?>
<dl class="zend_form">
    <?=$this->formInput ( $form->get( 'id' ) )?>

    <div>

    <?=$this->formLabel ( $form->get ( 'name' ) )?>
        <?=$this->formInput ( $form->get ( 'name' ) )?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors ( $form->get ( 'name' ) )?>
        <div id="nameInfo">Please enter your name?</div>
    </div>

    <div><?=$this->formLabel ( $form->get ( 'email' ) )?>
        <?=$this->formInput ( $form->get ( 'email' ) )?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors ( $form->get ( 'email' ) )?>
        <div id="emailInfo">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log
    in!</div>
    </div>

    <div><?=$this->formLabel ( $form->get ( 'site' ) )?>

        <?=$this->formInput ( $form->get ( 'site' ) )?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors ( $form->get ( 'site' ) )?>
    </div>

    <div><?=$this->formLabel ( $form->get ( 'comment' ) )?>
        <?=$this->formTextarea ( $form->get ( 'comment' ) )?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors ( $form->get ( 'comment' ) )?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?=$this->formInput ( $form->get ( 'submit' ) )?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors ( $form->get ( 'submit' ) )?>
    </div>
</dl>
<?=$this->form ()->closeTag ( $form )?>
```